# Blurry reflections using Principled BSDF in Blender 2.79 test build

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I did a quick test with the latest test build of Blender 2.79 (blender-2.78.0-git.db8bc1d-windows64) comparing reflections in a plane from an environment HDRI texture (free 8k "sunny_vondelpark" from HDRIHaven).

Using a horizontal plane with a simple Glossy BSDF with "Roughness = 0", the reflections are very sharp, but switching to the Principled BSDF with corresponding settings ("Metallic = 1" and "Roughness = 0") gives significant blurry reflections. Same results with 16k HDRI, as well as testing with "GGX" vs "Multiscatter GGX".

The Principled BSDF is configured with default values, except "Metallic = 1" and "Roughness = 0". I also recreated the Principled BSDF node just to make sure all other values were default, same results.

Please see rendered results below, what could be causing this...? The only thing I have changed is the shader for the plane, all other settings are the same.

**Update**: I also tested with importing an "Image as a plane", the reflection from this image is also blurred using the Principled BSDF, so the problem is not related to the HDRI setup.

**Update 2**: Same problem if using a procedural checker texture on the plane that is reflected.

*Note that if i give the Glossy BSDF a "Roughness = 0.001" the reflection is very similar to the Pricipled shader with "Roughness = 0".*

Rendered result with Glossy BSDF:
[image]

Rendered result with Principled BSDF:
[image]

Here's a comparison with checker texure as background taken fron top view:

[image]

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour. Quite strange, I currently have no idea. I hope someone can clarify this.

Comment: A few observations... First, 2.79 is beta and this is not the place to report bugs.  But, second, if you want a perfectly glossy shader, that's what the Glossy shader is for.  Third, to me, the Principled shader looks more realistic, that may be why they built in a little blur into the shader, there's no perfectly reflective surface. It's also taking Fresnel and several other factors into account.  But +1 anyway.

Comment: @bertmoog Thanks for your comments, I agree with you that the Principled shader takes much more properties into consideration for rendering realistic and physical correct materials, but in my humble opinion, the reflection is way to blurry compared to a real world mirror. I have now opened a bug report to get some feedback from the developers, see [this link](https://developer.blender.org/T52152).

Comment: And it's fixed. Was a bug (we clamped the lowest possible value to 0.001), can be closed now.